# 401 when fetching Discord channel messages using RestCord

Tags: php, restcord

I'm using Restcord ( Restcord.com ) to connect to Discord.
I'm using OAuth instead of Bot

```
use RestCord\DiscordClient;
$token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$discord = new DiscordClient(['token' => '$token','tokenType' => 'OAuth']); 
var_dump($discord->channel->getChannelMessages(['channel.id' => 924525404658749500]));
```

Yet I'm getting a 401 Unauthorised..
Its not private and the OAuth token creation was successful so I'm puzzled

Answer (score 0):

looks like its available only for bots token not for oauth2.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).